# Android - accessing var in class in class

Tags: java, android

I am making a module to include with all my applications. In this module, `onCreate` is overridden to perform code I like doing in all my apps, like using `SupportActionBar`. In all my applications, I have stuck to keeping my toolbar element `id` `toolbar`. I want the overridden function to access this, without actually giving it the id. I don't want to have to do `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, R.id.toolbar)` but `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, R.class)` or related, and get the function to get the variable on its own, like:

```
// In custom parent class
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, Class r) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Toolbar t = findViewById(r.getClass("id").getInt("toolbar"));
  setSupportActionBar(t);
}
// Main func
// Extends class in which above function resides
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
  super.onCreate(b, R.class);
}
```

Comment: Do you have actual example code of what you have and have tried so far? Also, have you went through any basic [Java tutorials/documentation](https://www.google.com/search?q=official+java+documentation&oq=official+java+documentation&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.5638j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=learn+java)? Because that would be the first step in building an Android application.

Comment: can you tell me what exactly you want to do....

Comment: Are you talking about the generated Resources class R, where you probably got R.id.tests_id from, or about a Class  you created called R, that you created with the the Class foo and method bar?

Comment: Android - I have that basic class R, and I'm passing class<?> R to another function to evaluate variables (& their values) in class R.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate"? (_"I want that function to evaluate `R.id.foo`"_)

Comment: I'll save it to a file, then use it to set toolbar, etc.

Comment: is this R the actual R ?? the auto generated class? if yes then WHY ? you can pass int which is R.id.xyz, you can pass the actual View corresponding to this ID... but passing R... WHY?

Answer (score 0):

In parameter should be object of Resources class. So:

```
// In custom parent class ( extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity )
public void doStuff(Resources r) {
 Toolbar t = findViewById(r.getClass("id").getInt("toolbar"))
 setSupportActionBar(t);
}
// Main func
// Extends class in which above function resides
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
  super.onCreate(b);
  doStuff(getResources()); //we have Resources
}
```

but i do not undestand what is purpose of sending R as method parameter. It can be done this way:

```
// In custom parent class
public void doStuff() {
 Toolbar t = findViewById(getResources().getClass("id").getInt("toolbar"))
 setSupportActionBar(t);
}
// Main func
// Extends class in which above function resides
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
  super.onCreate(b);
  doStuff();
}
```

Comment: The `Resources` class does not have a `getClass(String)` function (In Android 6.0, at least). This code does not compile.

Comment: I checked on AppCompatActivity and it works. If create app for older androids AppCompatActivity is best choice.

Comment: Cleaned & Upgraded to Nougat (from M). But this code still does not work! I am using android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity (for those wondering)